# Is it possibile to mount home directory (~) in a Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to run a simple Kubernetes Pod, and I want to mount the home of the host where the pod is scheduled into the `/hosthome` directory.

I'm using Kubernetes Python API to deploy those pods on a remote cluster (so I can't use something like `os.path.expanduser('~')` because it'll parse the "client" host home, not the remote one).

When I try to deploy the pod with this volume definition:

```
...
volumes:
  - name: hosthome
    hostPath:
      path: ~
...
```

The pod creation fails with this error: `create ~: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters`. So I can't use the `~` shortcut to mount it.

So, my question is: is there any way to mount the home directory of the host where the pod is scheduled using only the YAML definition (without replaces or Python functions)?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an identical home directory on every node the pod might run on?  Usually you'll just want to deploy a fixed image; Kubernetes really isn't designed at all to be a live development environment.

Comment: Yeah, I know it sounds a bit strange, but I'm using Kubernetes to run a network simulation tool and it needs the home directory... It's a "forced" use of Kubernetes, I know! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I think this is not possible. Only absolute paths are allowed for a host volumne mount.